# In JavaScript, is parseInt() a function or a method? (Some sources claim the former, while others the latter)

Tags: javascript, function, methods, parseint

I'm just trying to understand the difference between functions and methods, and parseInt() only brought more confusion to the table.

[According to mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), it's a function:

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

[While - for example - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) states it to be a method:

> The parseInt method parses a value as a string and returns the first integer.

Which one is it, then - a function or a method? And for future cases, how can I intuitively 'tell the two apart'?

Comment: If you find a conflict between MDN and w3schools, trust MDN. w3schools is better than it used to be, but still has quality and reliability issues.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/whats-the-difference-between-a-method-and-a-function maybe it can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-overview):

> A primitive value is a member of one of the following built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, BigInt, String, and Symbol; an object is a member of the built-in type Object; and a function is a callable object. **A function that is associated with an object via a property is called a method.**

Since `parseInt` isn't associated with an object, it's a function, not a method.

Comment: *Technically*, `parseInt` is a function property of the global object -- https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-parseint-string-radix :-) I still wouldn't call it a method, though, not least because it doesn't use any information from the object on which it's called, which I would consider a missing part of the definition the spec uses.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I knew someone would say that. ;-)